# Postgresql WALWrite

Tags: postgresql

I'll tell you right away that all read requests work fine. INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE and everything connected with it does not work. Waits continuously for the WALWrite state.

Symptoms - after restarting the server, the first couple of requests of any size are processed and then they start to hang. Regardless of the volume. It started after zabbix_agent used all connections to the database (I don't know why and how, now it is disabled).

Current setting
Server:
126GB RAM; 16CPU; SSD Disk

Pg conf:

wal_level = minimal

checkpoint_timeout = 60min

max_wal_size = 16GB

min_wal_size = 4GB

checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9

shared_buffers = 32GB

temp_buffers = 512MB

work_mem = 20MB

maintenance_work_mem = 2GB

autovacuum_work_mem = 4GB

Comment: What does the log file say?

Comment: zabbix_agent is probably the first victim here, not the perp.  If its old connections are permanently hung but it keeps launching new ones on schedule, then it will soon fill up all the connections.

Comment: The log is surprisingly empty. 
I limited the number of connections to the zabbix_agent now, checked the disk, the load was very large (but I still don't understand why). Server restart helped, but not a pleasant aftertaste. Full monitoring has not yet had time to connect, now this is the first task)